# SQL duplicate elimination for tables with columns using UNION or INTERSECT in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres the simplest possible query is

```
postgres=# select;
--
(1 row)
```

The result of this query is a relation with a single
tuple (row), i.e., the empty tuple.
So we get the relation `{()}`.

This is clearly semantically correct.

Now assume that you have a relation foo with 1 attribute
(value) and at least two tuples (rows).  For example,

```
foo
----
value
------
  1
  2
```

Now issue the following query

```
postgres=# select from foo;
--
(2 rows)
```

This is the bag `{(),()}` and this makes sense since
we are projection on an empty set of attributes and there are two tuples in foo.

What I want to do is to coerce this bag into a set
and obtain `{()}`.
This can be done with a group by as follows:

```
postgres=# select from foo group by();
--
(1 row)
```

And this is correct as well.

Another possibility, in general, to remove duplicates
is to use the `UNION` or `INTERSECT` operators of SQL
because they implicitly coerce bags into sets.

So for example, if `R` is a relation with duplicates,
the query

```
(select * from R) UNION (select * R)
```

or the query

```
(select * from R) INTERSECT (select * R)
```

will do the trick.

Now here is my observation (and question).

Consider the query

```
(select from foo) UNION (select from foo)
```

One would expect that the answer to this query is
the relation `{()}`, i.e., the relation in which the
duplicate empty tuples are removed.
However, when to do this query in postgresql you 
do not get this answer.

```
postgres=# (select from foo) UNION (select from foo);
--
(4 rows)
```

So, it appears that in this case the `UNION` operator
behaves exactly as the `UNION ALL` operator.

```
postgres=# (select from foo) UNION ALL (select from foo);
--
(4 rows)
```

But something even stranger happens with the `INTERSECT`
operator.   Consider the query

```
postgres=# (select from foo) INTERSECT (select from foo);
--
(4 rows)
```

So again you get 4 empty tuples where you expect
just 1  (or at most 2).

The same happens with the `INTERSECT ALL` operator

```
postgres=# (select from foo) INTERSECT ALL (select from foo);
--
(4 rows)
```

**Conclusion:**  It would appear that there is a bug in
postgresql when it comes down to the `UNION`, `INTERSECT` and `INTERSECT ALL`
operators where it concerns table with no attributes.

**Remark:**
One may wonder why one would consider such relations.
But they are actually very useful because a
relation with zero columns can be used as a mechanism
in query processing to reason with true and false

The relation `{()}` stands for `true` and the relation
`{}` stands for `false`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question.Please don't invent pseudocode.

Comment: @wildplasser Actually it is working code.

Comment: Comparing `unknown` with `unknown` provides `unknown` result [(Three-valued logic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic) Thats because the series of the `unknown` values assumes as them all different (or not equal from other side).

Comment: Interesting. My guess is that `(select from foo) INTERSECT (select from foo);` is a carthesian product, or is it a UNION?

Comment: @wildplasser Logically it should return the empty rowset (no common elements), but looking to the query plan `(select * from foo) INTERSECT (select * from foo);` contains `Intersect -> Append` steps and `(select from foo) INTERSECT (select from foo);` contains only `Append` step. Probably it is just the unforeseen situation for the planner... In any case IMO it is good question.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that *both* `UNION` and `INTERSECT` return 4 rows seems self-contradictory – either empty tuples are all equal (in which case the `UNION` should have fewer elements) or empty tuples are all not equal (in which case the `INTERSECT` should have fewer elements).

And an `INTERSECT` having *more* result rows than either input relation is clearly insane.

You should take this to the pgsql-hackers list or report it as a bug.

But I have to doubt your statement that these questions are of any practical value:

1. Empty `SELECT` lists are not standard compliant. They are a recently introduced implementation artifact in PostgreSQL. What keeps you from using the (SQL standard compliant) variant `SELECT 1 FROM ...`?
2. How can you interpret a result of one empty tuple as `true` and an empty result as `false`? What is the meaning of a result with two empty tuple? What does `UNION` and `INTERSECT` mean in this context?